# Get error on transparent image using huawei image segmentation

Tags: android, image-segmentation, huawei-mobile-services

```
MLImageSegmentationSetting analyzerSetting = (new MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory()).setExact(true).setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG).setScene(2).create();
        MLImageSegmentationSetting setting = new MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory().setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG).create();
        this.analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(analyzerSetting);//error on this line
```

error :
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.brandpost.brandpro365, PID: 9861
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2001, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/61/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/png/1980871995 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list {U(content)}} }} to activity {com.brandpost.brandpro365/com.mlkit.sample.activity.StillCutPhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5301)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5340)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
at com.huawei.agconnect.config.a.c.a(Unknown Source:0)
at com.huawei.agconnect.config.a.g.(Unknown Source:41)
at com.huawei.agconnect.config.a.a.getString(Unknown Source:43)
at com.huawei.agconnect.config.a.a.getString(Unknown Source:1)
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.AgConnectInfo.(AgConnectInfo.java:53)
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.MLApplicationSetting.fromResource(MLApplicationSetting.java:262)
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.MLApplication.initialize(MLApplication.java:180)
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.MLApplication.getInstance(MLApplication.java:125)
at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance(MLAnalyzerFactory.java:53)
at com.mlkit.sample.activity.StillCutPhotoActivity.createImageTransactor(StillCutPhotoActivity.java:149)
at com.mlkit.sample.activity.StillCutPhotoActivity.onActivityResult(StillCutPhotoActivity.java:101)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8382)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5340) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instuctions for HMS ML SDK : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/image-segmentation-0000001050040109

First, check the preparations:

1. Configure App info. in AGC: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/config-agc-0000001050990353
2. Enabling the service: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/enable-service-0000001050038078

Then, as for how to Create an image segmentation analyzer, please refer here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/image-segmentation-0000001050040109

```
// Method 1: Use default parameter settings to configure the image segmentation analyzer.
// The default mode is human body segmentation in fine mode. All segmentation results of human body segmentation are returned (pixel-level label information, human body image with a transparent background, gray-scale image with a white human body and black background, and an original image for segmentation).
MLImageSegmentationAnalyzer analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(); 
// Method 2: Use MLImageSegmentationSetting to customize the image segmentation analyzer.
MLImageSegmentationSetting setting = new MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory() 
    // Set whether to support fine segmentation. The value true indicates fine segmentation, and the value false indicates fast segmentation.
    .setExact(false) 
    // Set the segmentation mode to human body segmentation.
    .setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG) 
    // Set returned result types.
    // MLImageSegmentationScene.ALL: All segmentation results are returned (pixel-level label information, human body image with a transparent background, gray-scale image with a white human body and black background, and an original image for segmentation).
    // MLImageSegmentationScene.MASK_ONLY: Only pixel-level label information and an original image for segmentation are returned.
    // MLImageSegmentationScene.FOREGROUND_ONLY: A human body image with a transparent background and an original image for segmentation are returned.
    // MLImageSegmentationScene.GRAYSCALE_ONLY: A gray-scale image with a white human body and black background and an original image for segmentation are returned.
    .setScene(MLImageSegmentationScene.FOREGROUND_ONLY) 
 .create(); 
MLImageSegmentationAnalyzer analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(setting);
```